# Where is the definition of `map.clear()`?

Tags: flutter, dictionary, dart

I'm checking the implementation of `Map`. (map.dart in `dart:collection`)

I find `void clear();` in `abstract class Map<K, V>`. `clear()` doesn't have any implementation and `class Map` doesn't extend/implement any other classes. But I can still call `clear()`.

example

```dart
Map<int, int> m = <int, int>{1: 1, 2: 2};
m.clear();
```

Where can I find the implementation of `clear()`?

Comment: Can you check what it extends / implements? Also when you try to Go To Definition in the IDE, where does it lead you?

Comment: after clear() operation map will be empty {}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is based on the assumption that you want the implementation used when Dart is running natively and not on the web.

The default `Map` in Dart is a `LinkedHashMap`. There are several layers before getting the implementation of `clear()` but I expect this is the one you are looking for:

```dart
  void clear() {
    if (!isEmpty) {
      _index = _uninitializedIndex;
      _hashMask = _HashBase._UNINITIALIZED_HASH_MASK;
      _data = _uninitializedData;
      _usedData = 0;
      _deletedKeys = 0;
    }
  }
```

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/2.15.1/sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/compact_hash.dart#L333-L341

Answer (score 0):

The `{}` notation creates a `LinkedHashMap` and that's where you'll find the implementation. See:

```dart
import 'dart:collection';

void main () {

  Map<int, int> m = <int, int>{1: 1, 2: 2};
  if(m is LinkedHashMap) {
    print("It's a LinkedHashMap!");
  }
}
```

Output:

```
It's a LinkedHashMap!
```

Comment: Yeah, not really helpful since this clue just points you to: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/1278bd5adb6a857580f137e47bc521976222f7b9/sdk/lib/collection/linked_hash_map.dart#L22 which does not contain much implementation and not for `clear()`. ;)